# fopen and fclose, passing a file across functions

Tags: c, fopen, fread, fclose

I have a file that I open with fopen in a init function that I leave without closing because I want to fread() it in another function. In order to do this would I declare a global static file that all the functions can interact with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a file through a translation unit - scoped variable (i.e. a `static FILE *`) is acceptable. However, it leaves some doubts as to who is responsible for calling `fclose`. A better approach would be to have the function that opens the file return `FILE*` to the caller, with the assumption that the caller would later call `fclose`.

Better yet, let the function that calls `fread` also do the `fopen`: instead of opening the file, the first function could prepare the file name, and store it in a `static` variable. Then the reading function could call `fopen`, do `fread`s, and call `fclose` all in a single function.

Answer (score 2):

No; you would pass the file pointer to the functions as a parameter.

For example:

```
FILE *init( char *fname )
{
  FILE *fp = fopen( fname, "r" );
  return fp;
}

void read( FILE *fp )
{
  ...
  while ( fread( buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, fp ))
    // do stuff
}

int main( void )
{
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  ...
  fp = init( "myfile.txt" );
  if ( fp )
    read( fp );
  ...
}
```

Ideally, functions should communicate through parameters, return values, and exceptions (where available); sharing state through global variables leads to maintenance headaches.

Answer (score 1):

It depends in what scope you need the `FILE*` that `fopen()` returns. If you open the file in `main()`, you can just keep passing the file pointer to other functions as an input parameter. Something like:

```
int main ( void )
{
    FILE *pFile = fopen ( ... );

    // validate pFile

    SomeFunc ( pFile );

    ...

    fclose ( pFile );
}

void SomeFunc ( FILE *pF )
{
    ...

    fread ( ... );

    ...
}
```

Unless you really need it for some reason, I wouldn't declare the file pointer as a global variable - it's easy to forget to clean up globals correctly and in larger programs it's hard to see the life cycle of the variable.

The best approach is to keep the scope of the file as tight as possible - this makes it easy to read / maintain the code and releases resources sooner.